# c++ member function pointer problem

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I'm new to c++ . I want to know about object pointer and pointer to member function . I wrote a code which is following:

code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class golu
{
   int i;
public:
   void man()
   {
      cout<<"\ntry to learn \n";
   }
};
int main()
{
   golu m, *n;
   void golu:: *t =&golu::man(); //making pointer to member function

   n=&m;//confused is it object pointer
   n->*t();
}
```

but when i compile it it shows me two error which is following:

```
pcc.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
pcc.cpp:15: error: cannot declare pointer to ‘void’ member
pcc.cpp:15: error: cannot call member function ‘void golu::man()’ without object
pcc.cpp:18: error: ‘t’ cannot be used as a function.
```

my question are following :

1. What I'm doing wrong in this code ?
2. How to make object pointer ?
3. How to make pointer to member function of a class and how to use them ?

Please explain me these concept.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two errors corrected here:

```
int main()
{
   golu m, *n;
   void (golu::*t)() =&golu::man; 

   n=&m;
   (n->*t)();
}
```

1. you want a pointer to function
2. the priority of the operators is not the one you expected, I had to add parenthesis. `n->*t();` is interpreted as `(n->*(t()))` while you want `(n->*t)()`;

Comment: will you explain a bit about priorty? I don't understand the concept of priority  in this context.

Comment: Does the modified answer suit you?

Comment: It is what makes you consider 1 + 2 * 3 is 7 and not 9.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations

Answer (score 5):

A member function pointer has the following form:

```
R (C::*Name)(Args...)
```

Where `R` is the return type, `C` is the class type and `Args...` are any possible parameters to the function (or none).

With that knowledge, your pointer should look like this:

```
void (golu::*t)() = &golu::man;
```

Note the missing `()` after the member function. That would try to call the member function pointer you just got and thats not possible without an object.
Now, that gets much more readable with a simple typedef:

```
typedef void (golu::*golu_memfun)();
golu_memfun t = &golu::man;
```

Finally, you don't need a pointer to an object to use member functions, but you need parenthesis:

```
golu m;
typedef void (golu::*golu_memfun)();
golu_memfun t = &golu::man;
(m.*t)();
```

The parenthesis are important because the `()` operator (function call) has a higher priority (also called [precedence](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/language/operator_precedence)) than the `.*` (and `->*`) operator.

Answer (score 2):

'void golu:: *t =&golu::man();' should be changed to 'void (golu:: *t)() =&golu::man;' you are trying to use pointer to function not pointer to result of a static function!

Answer (score 1):

(1) Function pointer is not declared properly.

(2) You should declare like this:

```
void (golu::*t) () = &golu::man;
```

(3) Member function pointer should be used with object of the `class`.