# When do extra parentheses have an effect, other than on operator precedence?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, parentheses, c++-faq

Parentheses in C++ are used in many places: e.g. in function calls and grouping expressions to override operator precedence. **Apart from illegal extra parentheses** (such as around function call argument lists), a general -but not absolute- rule of C++ is that **extra parentheses never hurt**:

**5.1 Primary expressions [expr.prim]**

**5.1.1 General [expr.prim.general]**

> 6 A parenthesized expression is a primary expression whose type and
>   value are identical to those of the enclosed expression. The presence
>   of parentheses does not affect whether the expression is an lvalue.
>   The parenthesized expression can be used in exactly the same contexts
>   as those where the enclosed expression can be used, and with the same
>   meaning, **except as otherwise indicated**.

**Question**: in which contexts do extra parentheses change the meaning of a C++ program, other than overriding basic operator precedence?

**NOTE**: I consider the restriction of **pointer-to-member** syntax to `&qualified-id` without parentheses to be outside the scope because it [**restricts syntax**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7135001/819272) rather than allowing two syntaxes with different meanings. Similarly, the use of **parentheses inside preprocessor macro definitions** also guards against unwanted operator precedence.

Comment: "I consider the &(qualified-id) resolution to pointer-to-member to be an application of operator precedence." -- Why is that? If you omit the parentheses in `&(C::f)`, the operand of `&` is still `C::f`, is it not?

Comment: @hvd `expr.unary.op/4`: A pointer to member is only formed when an explicit `&` is used and its operand is a qualified-id not enclosed in parentheses.

Comment: Right, so what does that have to do with operator precedence? (Nevermind, your edited question clears that up.)

Comment: @hvd updated, I was confusing the RHS with the LHS in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6262793/819272), and there the parens are used to override the precedence of the function call `()` over the pointer-to-member selector `::*`

Comment: I think you should be a bit more precise about which cases need consideration. For instance parentheses around a type name to make it a C-style cast operator (whatever the context) do not make a parenthesised expression at all. On the other hand I would say technically the condition after **if** or **while** is a parenthesised expression, but since the parentheses are part of the syntax here they should not be considered. Nor should IMO any case be, where without out the parentheses the expression would no longer be parsed as a single unit, whether operator precedence is involved or not.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

### TL;DR

Extra parentheses change the meaning of a C++ program in the following contexts:

- preventing argument-dependent name lookup
- enabling the comma operator in list contexts
- ambiguity resolution of vexing parses
- deducing referenceness in `decltype` expressions
- preventing preprocessor macro errors

### Preventing argument-dependent name lookup

As is detailed in Annex A of the Standard, a `post-fix expression` of the form `(expression)` is a `primary expression`, but not an `id-expression`, and therefore not an `unqualified-id`. This means that argument-dependent name lookup is prevented in function calls of the form `(fun)(arg)` compared to the conventional form `fun(arg)`.

**3.4.2 Argument-dependent name lookup [basic.lookup.argdep]**

> 1 When **the postfix-expression in a function call (5.2.2) is an
>   unqualified-id**, other namespaces not considered during the usual
>   unqualified lookup (3.4.1) may be searched, and in those namespaces,
>   namespace-scope friend function or function template declarations
>   (11.3) not otherwise visible may be found. These modifications to the
>   search depend on the types of the arguments (and for template template
>   arguments, the namespace of the template argument). [ Example:

```
namespace N {
    struct S { };
    void f(S);
}

void g() {
    N::S s;
    f(s);   // OK: calls N::f
    (f)(s); // error: N::f not considered; parentheses
            // prevent argument-dependent lookup
}
```

> —end example ]

### Enabling the comma operator in list contexts

The comma operator has a special meaning in most list-like contexts (function and template arguments, initializer lists etc.). Parentheses of the form `a, (b, c), d` in such contexts can enable the comma operator compared to the regular form `a, b, c, d` where the comma operator does not apply.

**5.18 Comma operator [expr.comma]**

> 2 In contexts where comma is given a special meaning, [ Example: **in
>   lists of arguments to functions (5.2.2) and lists of initializers
>   (8.5)** —end example ] the comma operator as described in Clause 5 can
>   appear only in parentheses. [ Example:

```
f(a, (t=3, t+2), c);
```

> has three arguments, the second of which has the value 5. —end example
>   ]

### Ambiguity resolution of vexing parses

Backward compatibility with C and its arcane function declaration syntax can lead to surprising parsing ambiguities, known as vexing parses. Essentially, **anything that can be parsed as a declaration will be parsed as one**, even though a competing parse would also apply.

**6.8 Ambiguity resolution [stmt.ambig]**

> 1 **There is an ambiguity in the grammar involving expression-statements
>   and declarations**: An expression-statement with a function-style
>   explicit type conversion (5.2.3) as its leftmost subexpression can be
>   indistinguishable from a declaration where the first declarator starts
>   with a (. **In those cases the statement is a declaration**.

**8.2 Ambiguity resolution [dcl.ambig.res]**

> 1 **The ambiguity arising from the similarity between a function-style
>   cast and a declaration mentioned in 6.8 can also occur in the context
>   of a declaration**. In that context, the choice is between a function
>   declaration with a redundant set of parentheses around a parameter
>   name and an object declaration with a function-style cast as the
>   initializer. Just as for the ambiguities mentioned in 6.8, the
>   resolution is to **consider any construct that could possibly be a
>   declaration a declaration**. [ Note: A declaration can be explicitly
>   disambiguated by a nonfunction-style cast, by an = to indicate
>   initialization or by removing the redundant parentheses around the
>   parameter name. —end note ] [ Example:

```
struct S {
    S(int);
};

void foo(double a) {
    S w(int(a));  // function declaration
    S x(int());   // function declaration
    S y((int)a);  // object declaration
    S z = int(a); // object declaration
}
```

> —end example ]

A famous example of this is the [**Most Vexing Parse**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1424510/819272), a name popularized by Scott Meyers in Item 6 of his [**Effective STL**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629) book:

```
ifstream dataFile("ints.dat");
list<int> data(istream_iterator<int>(dataFile), // warning! this doesn't do
               istream_iterator<int>());        // what you think it does
```

This declares a function, `data`, whose return type is `list<int>`. The
function data takes two parameters:

- The first parameter is named `dataFile`. It's type is `istream_iterator<int>`. The
  parentheses around `dataFile` are superfluous and are ignored.
- The second parameter has no name. Its type is pointer to function taking
  nothing and returning an `istream_iterator<int>`.

Placing extra parentheses around the first function argument (parentheses around the second argument are illegal) will resolve the ambiguity

```
list<int> data((istream_iterator<int>(dataFile)), // note new parens
                istream_iterator<int>());          // around first argument
                                                  // to list's constructor
```

C++11 has brace-initializer syntax that allows to side-step such parsing problems in many contexts.

### Deducing referenceness in `decltype` expressions

In contrast to `auto` type deduction, `decltype` allows referenceness (lvalue and rvalue references) to be deduced. The rules distinguish between `decltype(e)` and `decltype((e))` expressions:

**7.1.6.2 Simple type specifiers [dcl.type.simple]**

> 4 For an expression `e`, **the type denoted by `decltype(e)`** is defined as
>   follows:
>
> — if `e` is an unparenthesized id-expression or an
>   unparenthesized class member access (5.2.5), `decltype(e)` is the type
>   of the entity named by `e`. If there is no such entity, or if `e` names a
>   set of overloaded functions, the program is ill-formed;
>
> — otherwise,
>   if `e` is an xvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&&`, where `T` is the type of `e`;
>
> —
>   otherwise, if `e` is an lvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&`, where `T` is the type
>   of `e`;
>
> — otherwise, `decltype(e)` is the type of `e`.
>
> The operand of the
>   decltype specifier is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5). [ Example:

```
const int&& foo();
int i;
struct A { double x; };
const A* a = new A();
decltype(foo()) x1 = 0;   // type is const int&&
decltype(i) x2;           // type is int
decltype(a->x) x3;        // type is double
decltype((a->x)) x4 = x3; // type is const double&
```

> —end example ] [ Note: The rules for determining types involving
>   `decltype(auto)` are specified in 7.1.6.4. —end note ]

The rules for `decltype(auto)` have a similar meaning for extra parentheses in the RHS of the initializing expression. Here's an example from the [**C++FAQ**](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#decltype-auto) and [**this related Q&A**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24121708/819272)

```
decltype(auto) look_up_a_string_1() { auto str = lookup1(); return str; }  //A
decltype(auto) look_up_a_string_2() { auto str = lookup1(); return(str); } //B
```

The first returns `string`, the second returns `string &`, which is a reference to the local variable `str`.

### Preventing preprocessor macro related errors

There is a host of subtleties with preprocessor macros in their interaction with the C++ language proper, the most common of which are listed below

- using parentheses around macro parameters inside the macro definition `#define TIMES(A, B) (A) * (B);` in order to avoid unwanted operator precedence (e.g. in `TIMES(1 + 2, 2 + 1)` which yields 9 but would yield 6 without the parentheses around `(A)` and `(B)`
- using parentheses around macro arguments having commas inside: `assert((std::is_same<int, int>::value));` which would otherwise not compile
- using parentheses around a function to protect against macro expansion in included headers: `(min)(a, b)` (with the unwanted side effect of also disabling ADL)

Comment: Does not really change the program meaning, but best practice and affects the warnings emitted by the compiler: extra parentheses should be used in `if`/`while` if the expression is an assignment. E.g. `if (a = b)` -- warning (did you mean `==`?), while `if ((a = b))` -- no warning.

Comment: @Csq thanks, good observation, but that is a warning by a particular compiler and not mandated by the Standard. I don't think that fits within the language-lawyer nature of this Q&A.

Comment: Does `(min)(a, b)` (with evil MACRO `min(A, B)`) is part of argument-dependent name lookup prevention ?

Comment: @Jarod42 I guess so, but let's consider such [and other evil macros](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/30124) to be outside the scope of the question :-)

Comment: @TemplateRex I'm not sure that it's outside the scope of what the OP asked, but taking macros into consideration does introduce a number of additional  issues.

Comment: @Csq Best practice would be to not do assignment in a condition.

Comment: @JamesKanze do you mean things like parentheses protecting macro arguments with commas, e.g. templates inside macros `assert((std::is_same<int,  int>::value)));`?

Comment: @TemplateRex Amongst others.  There's the already mentioned use of parentheses to prevent finding a function style macro as well, and probably a few other special cases I've not considered.  The syntax when preprocessing is different from that when parsing, and parentheses can impact differently.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Note that OP and TemplateRex are the same person ^_^

Comment: @Oktalist this was quoted from Effective STL, and obviously that seems to be no longer true. I will try to find an issue in the Standard to find out when this was resolved.

Comment: @Oktalist it appaers that this has always been in the language, but perhaps at the time Meyers wrote the item, his compilers only accepted pasrens around the first param.

Comment: You might want to add an example to the quote from 5.18 using brackets `[]`. Also, the first time in that section you want `comma` and not `comma operator`.

Comment: @Deduplicator the answer is quite long already, and I skipped an example using `initializer_list`. The comma operator is abused enough as it is :-)

Answer (score 4):

In general, in programming languages, "extra" parentheses implies that they are *not* changing the syntactical parsing order or meaning. They are being added to clarify the order (operator precedence) for the benefit of people reading the code, and their only effect would be to slightly slow the compile process, and reduce human errors in understanding the code (probably speeding up the overall development process).

If a set of parentheses actually *changes* the way an expression is parsed, then they are by definition **not** extra. Parentheses that turn an illegal/invalid parse into a legal one are not "extra", although that *may* point out a poor language design.

Comment: exactly, and this is the general rule in C++ as well (see the Standard quote in the question), **except as otherwise indicated**. To point out these "weaknesses" was the purpose of this Q&A.