# How is 'A(tmpVector);' the same as 'A tmpVector;'?

Tags: c++, c++11

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24155026/c-call-constructor-within-another-constructor-of-the-same-class) has this code snippet:

```
A::A(const char *pc) {
    A(string(pc));
}

A::A(string s) {
    vector<string> tmpVector;
    tmpVector.push_back(s);
    A(tmpVector); // <-- error
}

// Constructor
A::A(vector<string> filePathVector) {
}
```

The problem is that `A(tmpVector);` conflicts with `vector<string> tmpVector;`:

```
error: conflicting declaration 'A  tmpVector'
error: 'tmpVector' has a previous declaration as 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > tmpVector'
```

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24155042/65863) says:

> This
>
> A(tmpVector);
>
> is the same as this
>
> A tmpVector; // but there is already an object called tmpVector

With an added comment:

> In this context, the () are superfluous.

My question is: why are the parenthesis superfluous?  What exactly in the C++11 spec makes that so?  I have not seen this before.

Comment: It's not related to C++11 http://ideone.com/MFGKSQ

Comment: Closely related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116817/when-do-extra-parentheses-have-an-effect-other-than-on-operator-precedence

Comment: Yeah basically another dupe of "what is MVP"?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Really? How is that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From §8 [dcl.decl] of the standard:

> Declarators have the syntax:

```
declarator:
    ptr-declarator
    noptr-declarator parameters-and-qualifiers trailing-return-type
ptr-declarator:
    noptr-declarator
    ptr-operator ptr-declarator
noptr-declarator:
    declarator-id attribute-specifier-seq_opt
    noptr-declarator parameters-and-qualifiers
    noptr-declarator [ constant-expression_opt] attribute-specifier-seq_opt
    ( ptr-declarator )
```

(Remainder of grammar omitted).

In particular, note that

1. A `ptr-declarator` is a `declarator`.
2. Something of the form `( ptr-declarator )` is a `noptr-declarator` which in turn is a `ptr-declarator`.

In other words, you can have as many pairs of parentheses as you want and it's still a declarator. Now this causes an ambiguity in cases like `T(x);`, which is resolved by §6.8 [stmt.ambig] of the standard:

> There is an ambiguity in the grammar involving expression-statements
>   and declarations: An expression statement with a function-style
>   explicit type conversion (5.2.3) as its leftmost subexpression can be
>   indistinguishable from a declaration where the first declarator starts
>   with a (. In those cases the statement is a declaration.

The example accompanying that paragraph directly covers this case:

```
class T {
// ...
public:
    T();
    T(int);
    T(int, int);
};

T(a);        // declaration
T(*b)();     // declaration
T(c)=7;      // declaration
T(d),e,f=3;  // declaration
extern int h;
T(g)(h,2);   // declaration
```