# Is `auto(expr)` treated as cast at the beginning of the expression statement?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++23

I have a simple code snippet shown below (https://godbolt.org/z/cPT3PhYdj):

```cpp
int main() {
  int x = 1;
  auto(1); // ok in GCC, error in Clang
  auto{1}; // ok in GCC, error in Clang
  static_cast<void>(auto(x)); // ok
  auto{x}; // ok in GCC, error in Clang
  auto(x); // both error in GCC an Clang
}
```

Where both GCC and Clang emit an error showing:

```
// by GCC Trunk [-std=c++23]
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:7:3: error: declaration of 'auto x' has no initializer
    7 |   auto(x); // why
      |   ^~~~
Compiler returned: 1

// by Clang Trunk [-std=c++2b]
<source>:3:8: error: expected unqualified-id
  auto(1); // why
       ^
<source>:3:8: error: expected ')'
<source>:3:7: note: to match this '('
  auto(1); // why
      ^
<source>:4:7: error: expected unqualified-id
  auto{1}; // why
      ^
<source>:6:7: error: expected unqualified-id
  auto{x}; // why
      ^
<source>:7:8: error: redefinition of 'x'
  auto(x); // why
       ^
<source>:2:7: note: previous definition is here
  int x = 1;
      ^
<source>:7:8: error: declaration of variable 'x' with deduced type 'auto' requires an initializer
  auto(x); // why
       ^
6 errors generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

- If C++23 is experimental, and will they be able to fix the ambiguity or change the disambiguation since another `auto(expr)` is introduced, or just leave it be?
- Are these expressions supposed to be parsed as explicit type decay conversion `auto(expr)` or `auto{expr}` in expression statements or parsed as a declaration?
- If there is no ambiguity, then which priority comes first:

  - `auto(identifier)` as `auto identifier`?, or
  - `auto(identifier)` as cast expression?

Comment: fyi if you are relying on `-std=c++23` features then at present this only has partial support.

Comment: Dup of [How is 'A(tmpVector);' the same as 'A tmpVector;'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24155571/how-is-atmpvector-the-same-as-a-tmpvector)

Comment: It's just weird how special these parentheses are when it comes to `noptr-declarator` being equivalent to `(ptr-declarator)` just to support pointer/reference to function/array declaration grammar.

Comment: @DesmondGold `auto(x)` when used as an expression will behave as an expression. On the other hand it(`auto(x);`) can also be a declaration. This is one of the examples showing how C++ is a **context-sensitive language**. See the [demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aaigT15RIzS6vDG8) added at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Explicit cast conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast):

> ```
> auto ( expression )   (8)     (since C++23)
>
> auto { expression }   (9)     (since C++23)
> ```
>
> 8,9) The `auto` specifier is replaced with the deduced type of the invented variable `x` declared with `auto x(expression);` (which is never interpreted as a function declaration) or `auto x{expression};` respectively. The result is always a prvalue of an object type.

So your usage seems to be allowed(in accordance with ) by the above quoted statement.

[Here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/79giE12Gpm7KPVfp) is a working demo of your code. Note in the linked demo, only the usage `auto(x)` produces an error, all other cases work fine.

---

Also note that from [PR105516](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=105516):

> `auto(x);` is interpreted as `auto x;`. Use `+auto(x);` if you want that to be an expression.

---

> If there is no ambiguity, then which priority comes first:

This is one of the examples showing how C++ is a **context sensitive language**. A construct cannot always be understood without knowing its wider contexts. Consider the following example:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 0   ;
    int k       ;
//------vvvvvvv----->here auto(x) is behaves as an expression as it is used as an expression 
    k = auto(x) ;

    auto(p)     ;  //this a declaration and not an explicit case unlike the above
}
```

Comment: From [PR105516](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=105516): "*Not a bug, "auto(x);" is interpreted as "auto x;".  Use +auto(x); if you want that to be an expression.*"

Comment: @康桓瑋 Yeah, i was wondering how C++23 resolve that ambiguity. As you mentioned, it resolves it by having a `+` before `auto(x)`. I have added that note in my answer with the appropriate citation/reference. Thanks.

Comment: So what is your conclusion? I don't see C++23 resolve this ambiguity.

Comment: I'd rather use `(auto(x))`, `+` isn't necessarily overloaded.

Comment: @康桓瑋 My conclusion is that it would make more sense to interpret `auto(x)` as a declaration instead of explicit cast. Additionally, as mentioned in [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=105516) gcc resolves this by having a `+` before `auto(x)` for explicit cast case. Moreover i am not sure how C++23(if this is indeed an ambiguity) resolves this.

Comment: @康桓瑋: There is no ambiguity to resolve. C++23 does not change the meaning of `auto(x)`, so nothing is ambiguous.

Comment: I think `(auto(x))` and `auto{x}` are enough

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell [the paper](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0849r8.html) introducing this feature didn't make any further relevant changes except to allow `auto` as type specifier in a functional-style explicit cast.

So intuitively `auto` here should behave the same as any other type specifier would.

For example, replacing `auto` with `int`, it is expected that all of these cases work and are functional-style explicit casts, except

```
int(x); // auto(x);
```

This one could according to the grammar also be a declaration of a variable named `x` of type `int` (or placeholder type) with parentheses around the declarator and without initializer.

As usual, the grammar is disambiguated by preferring the interpretation as declaration (see [[stmt.ambig]/1](https://www.eel.is/c++draft/stmt.ambig#1)). At least, I don't think that it should be different for `auto`. A declaration with `auto` placeholder type requires an initializer, which is not present in this interpretation, but according to [[stmt.ambig]/3](https://www.eel.is/c++draft/stmt.ambig#3) the disambiguation is supposed to be done very early and purely syntactic even if it ends up in an ill-formed declaration. I am not completely sure but I guess this should mean that `auto(x);` should still be disambiguated as a declaration.

I don't know why Clang gives errors for many of the other lines. I suppose the feature is either implemented only partially or these are implementation bugs (it is a very new feature in an unfinished standard revision).

Comment: You can refer to the [Demo section](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0849r8.html#Demo) in the original paper, https://godbolt.miator.net/z/Ks43an, modified clang that implements P0849 still rejects `auto(x)`, so I think it should be intentional?

Comment: @康桓瑋 I don't think any of the demos actually demonstrate the situations in the question.

Comment: @康桓瑋 The modified clang seems to reject the same lines as Clang rejects in the question, including e.g. `auto{1};`. That doesn't seem correct to me.

Comment: Marek Polacek (the guy who [implemented GCC's P0849R8](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/93810fd673654db9ff16170624a6d36449eab241)) thinks `auto(x)` should be rejected in this [PR](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=105516), while Jonathan Wakely said in my [PR](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=103653) last year that "*Yes this changed in C++23 so auto(x) creates an rvalue of the decayed type of x*", so I don't really know what's going on.

Comment: @康桓瑋 I am also not completely sure, but I think it would be surprising if `auto(x);` was _not_ an ill-formed declaration, while e.g. `using T = const int; T(x);` would be. In any case I think the _other_ cases in the question should definitively work.

Comment: I just realized that the [guy who implemented Clang's P0849R8](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/136b2931292083c8d69c09de9b952c86417b2c5d) is also the author of P0849R8...

Comment: @康桓瑋 That would explain why the demo implementation behaves the same. There is a FIXME in the commit indicating that `auto(&a)->n = 0;` should be treated as expression statement, but currently isn't. There doesn't seem to be any other test case in which a statement starts with `auto(` or `auto{`. I think that indicates that Clang's differing behavior from GCC is by mistake or partial implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I think `auto(x)` (where `x` is literally an identifier) can still have different meanings in different contexts and thus is subject to [[dcl.ambig.res]](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ambig.res) in C++23.

Unfortunately, the ambiguity is unlikely to be fixed. In the following program (well-formed since C++11), `auto(x) = Bar{};` is interpreted as a declaration. If `auto(x)` were "fixed", `auto(x) = Bar{};` would become an expression statement, which would change the existing behavior.

```
#include <cstdio>
struct Bar {
    Bar()
    {
        std::puts("initialization");
    }
};

struct Foo {
    void operator=(Bar)
    {
        std::puts("assignment");
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo x{};
    {
        auto(x) = Bar{}; // only prints "initialization"
    }
}
```