# Is auto(x); considered a declaration of a variable named x or an explicit type cast in C++23

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, auto, c++23

I came across [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=105516#c1) which states:

> Not a bug, `auto(x);` is interpreted as `auto x;`.  Use `+auto(x);` if you want that to be an expression.

The above seems to imply that since `auto(x);` is a declaration(equivalent to `auto x;`) it should be rejected since we're using `auto` and don't have an initializer.

While [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=103653#c4) states:

> Yes this changed in C++23 so auto(X) creates an rvalue of the decayed type of x.

---

The above quoted statements seems to be contradicting each other. So my question is what does the C++23 standard say about this? I mean is `auto(x);` a declaration or a explicit type cast.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72153420/is-autoexpr-treated-as-cast-at-the-beginning-of-the-expression-statement)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the code referenced by the GCC bug in question:

```
int main() {
  int x = 0;
  float t;
  t = auto(x);
}
```

`auto(x)` here is not a statement; it is unequivocally an expression. If `auto(x)` is used as an expression, it will behave as an expression. If it however is used in a way that makes it a statement, then it will behave as such.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense.