# Why in this case does argument-dependent lookup not considered?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

This question is based on C++11 Standard (N3092).

---

3.4.2-1 *Argument-dependent name lookup* says

> **When the postfix-expression in a function call (5.2.2) is an unqualified-id**, other namespaces not considered during the usual unqualified lookup (3.4.1) may be searched, and in those namespaces, namespace-scope friend function declarations (11.4) not otherwise visible may be found. These modifications to the search depend on the types of the arguments (and for template template arguments, the namespace of the template argument). [ Example:

```
namespace N {
    struct S { };
    void f(S);
}

void g() {
    N::S s;
    f(s); // OK: calls N::f
    (f)(s); // error: N::f not considered; parentheses
            // prevent argument-dependent lookup
}
```

> — end example ]

, but I don't understand why `(f)(s)` suppresses ADL(argument-dependent lookup). **This is what I would like to ask.**

According to 5.2.2-1 *Function call*,

> A function call is a postfix expression followed by parentheses containing a possibly empty, comma-separated list of expressions which constitute the arguments to the function.

so in that case, `f` or `(f)` are a postfix expression.

Then the syntax category of *postfix-expression* is defined as

> postfix-expression:
>
> primary-expression
>
> postfix-expression [ expression ]
>
> postfix-expression [ braced-init-list ]
>
> postfix-expression ( expression-list opt )
>
> simple-type-specifier ( expression-list opt )
>
> typename-specifier ( expression-list opt )
>
> simple-type-specifier braced-init-list
>
> typename-specifier braced-init-list
>
> postfix-expression . template opt id-expression
>
> postfix-expression -> template opt id-expression
>
> postfix-expression . pseudo-destructor-name
>
> postfix-expression -> pseudo-destructor-name
>
> postfix-expression ++
>
> postfix-expression --
>
> dynamic_cast < type-id > ( expression )
>
> static_cast < type-id > ( expression )
>
> reinterpret_cast < type-id > ( expression )
>
> const_cast < type-id > ( expression )
>
> typeid ( expression )
>
> typeid ( type-id )

In this case, only *primary-expression* is relevant. It is defined as

> primary-expression:
>
> literal
>
> this
>
> ( expression )
>
> id-expression
>
> lambda-expression

In this case, only *id-expression* is relevant, and it is defined as

> id-expression:
>
> unqualified-id
>
> qualified-id

So `f` and `(f)` are one of these. If `(f)` is not an unqualified-id (because ADL is suppressed), it should be one of *qualified-id*. But it is defined as

> qualified-id:
>
> :: opt nested-name-specifier template opt unqualified-id
>
> :: identifier
>
> :: operator-function-id
>
> :: literal-operator-id
>
> :: template-id

I think `(f)` is not one of these. If so, why `(f)(s)` suppresses ADL?

---

Supplement:

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24116818/8776746) (which was given in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55285036/why-in-this-case-does-argument-dependent-lookup-not-considered#comment97299971_55285036)) says

> As is detailed in Annex A of the Standard, a `post-fix expression` of the form `(expression)` is a `primary expression`, but not an `id-expression`, and therefore not an `unqualified-id`. This means that argument-dependent name lookup is prevented in function calls of the form `(fun)(arg)` compared to the conventional form `fun(arg)`.

but it is correct? The syntax category of *expression* is defined as

> expression:
>
> assignment-expression
>
> expression , assignment-expression

in Annex A. I don't think `f` in `(f)` is one of *expression*.

Comment: Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116817/when-do-extra-parentheses-have-an-effect-other-than-on-operator-precedence).  Trying to see if there is a better target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(f)` is `(` *expression* `)`, not *unqualified-id*, therefore ADL doesn't apply. A parenthesized *unqualified-id* is no longer an *unqualified-id*. In some cases, the standard says that "possibly parenthesized" X is equivalent to X. Argument-dependent lookup is not one of those cases.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please see my supplement? I don't think `f` belongs to the syntax category of *expression*.

Comment: @ynn `f` is an *expression* because it is an *assignment-expression*, which is because it's a *conditional-expression*, which is because it's a *logical-or-expression*, and so on.

Comment: Thank you. I finally returned to *postfix-expression* (to which `f` belongs) after many jumps.