# Calling object method saved in structure (MSVC2010)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Have a structure:

```
scheduled_call {
    MyClass* object;
    int value;
    void (MyClass::*setter)(const int)
}
```

For class:

```
MyClass {
    void doSomething(const int);
}
```

The structure compiles all well, but when I try to call the value as function, it throws error:

I need to execute call saved in this structure. I tried this:

```
void executeIt(scheduled_call cl) {
    cl.object->*(cl.method)(cl.value);
}
```

But I get:

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
```

My coding is based on [C/C++ function pointer guide](http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html#defi). I'm doing this as an experiment, if it fails I can fallback to `switch` statement of course.

Can anybody compile this under Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262712/c-member-function-pointer-problem) (second answer specifically) is a good reference for member function pointer syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in method call. This is **wrong**:

```
cl.object->*(cl.method)(cl.value);
```

This is **correct**:

```
(cl.object->*cl.method)(cl.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a valid member function pointer definition in your `struct`:

```
scheduled_call {
    MyClass* object;
    int value;
    void (MyClass::*method)(int); // <<<<
}
```

Comment: Hello, I'm really sorry, I accidentally created this mistake when writing the question. My actual code looks like this in the structure: `void (ComplexStyle::ValueCondition::*setter)(const QString &);` And it compiles. What doesn't compile is the call, not the definition.

Answer (score 1):

```
void MyClass::*method;
```

Is not a valid function pointer to a class memeber function.  To get that we need

```
void (MyClass::*method)(int)
```

An now `method` is a pointer to  function like `MyClass::doSomething()`

Comment: @tobi303 I am not sure as I have not seen that syntax.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ would it still be wrong though since we cant have a void member variable?

Comment: @tobi303 a pointer to a member variable of type void, what clearly is not a valid declaration and shouldn't compile, but I'm not sure what the standard has to say about it.

Comment: @brunocodutra I also think it shouldn't compile, but OP probably didn't show all of the error messages.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I didnt try it before (because i had to fetch the bus ;), now I did and indeed the compiler says `error: cannot declare pointer to 'void' member`

Comment: Sorry, I created mistake when writing the question. Original code looks just as you propose. The error is caused by calling the property as method, not by defining the structure. Bot definition and assignment compiles.